# Sails JS helpers error resolving/ rejecting

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using Helpers in Sails for login.
This is my **helpers/login.js**:

```
  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    const password = inputs.password;
    const email = inputs.email;

    // find user with email
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if (user){
      const salt = user.salt;
      const hashedPass = user.password;
      const iterations = user.iterations;

      // check if input password matches with password in DB
      crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, 64, 'sha512',
        (err, key) => {
          if (!err) {
            if (hashedPass === key.toString('hex')) {
              // password matched
              return exits.success({code: 200});
            }

          }
        });
    }
    // account not found or password doesnt match
    return exits.success({code: 404});


  }
```

**UserController.js**:

```
login: async function(req, res){
    let loginUser;
    try {    
      loginUser = await sails.helpers.login.with({
        email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password
      });


    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error login in usercontroller ", e.message);
      return res.serverError();
    }

    if (loginUser.code == 200) {
      return res.ok();

    }else {
      return res.serverError();
    }

  }
```

The problem lies in the Helper when I have the **right** **email** and **password** it's meant to return a `code: 200` although it returns `code: 404`. With error message from node:

```
WARNING: Something seems to be wrong with this function.
It is trying to signal that it has finished AGAIN, after
already resolving/rejecting once.
(silently ignoring this...)
```

, same when I input wrong username/ email it returns that message. But when I remove `return exits.success({code: 404})` and input right email and password, it returns the right code (200). I need help fixing it.

Comment: I suspect the problem is because of the pbkdf2 callback function. It returns     `return exits.success({code: 404});` and `return exits.success({code: 200});` I still have to learn the async environment so please if anyone have any reference it will be great! My solution now is to use **bcrypt** module as it supports async/ await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are trying to return an error code as a 'success' exit. In your `exits` object, you should make one like `notFound: { responseType: 'notFound' }`, then when you want to use it in your code, you do `return exits.notFound()`. Here is an example: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2

Comment: Read the question again. I have an error message of 

`WARNING: Something seems to be wrong with this function.
It is trying to signal that it has finished AGAIN, after
already resolving/rejecting once.
(silently ignoring this...)`

Comment: Ok now I have a little better of an idea. What is happening is that your 404 exit is getting triggered no matter what, because the 200 exit is within a callback that is not getting executed until after the 404. That means on a successful login, the exit is getting called twice. The simplest solution is to use await instead of a callback.